# Problem with the SDK Azure for FACE API With FileStream picture

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-services

We try to use the sdk to use the cognitives services of Microsoft. We use the Interface IFaceOperatiosn which inside there's a method to send a picture by stream like:DetectWithStreamWithHttpMessagesAsync. When we try to use it, we reach a APIErrorException which the message is Bad request but don't know where is the problem so there's our code:

```
public async Task<List<FaceAPI.Face>> DetectFace(string picture)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream img = new FileStream(picture, FileMode.Open);
                var res = await detect.DetectWithStreamWithHttpMessagesAsync(img);
                List<FaceAPI.Face> result = new List<FaceAPI.Face>();
                for (int i = 0; i < res.Body.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Add(new FaceAPI.Face { Age = (double)res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.Age, Bald = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.Hair.Bald > 0.5 ? true : false, Beard = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.FacialHair.Beard > 0.5 ? true : false, Gender = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.Gender.Value.Equals(Gender.Male) ? true : false, Glasses = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.Glasses.Value.Equals(GlassesType.NoGlasses) ? false : true, Hair = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.Hair.HairColor.ToString(), Moustache = res.Body[i].FaceAttributes.FacialHair.Moustache > 0.5 ? true : false,Rectangle=new System.Drawing.Rectangle { X = res.Body[i].FaceRectangle.Left, Y = res.Body[i].FaceRectangle.Top, Height = res.Body[i].FaceRectangle.Height, Width = res.Body[i].FaceRectangle.Width } });
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (APIErrorException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (ValidationException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Normally it returns a list of Face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a wich attribute you want retrieve for the detection like this:

```
var requiredFaceAttributes = new FaceAttributeType[] {
                    FaceAttributeType.Age,
                    FaceAttributeType.Hair,
                    FaceAttributeType.Gender,
                    FaceAttributeType.Smile,
                    FaceAttributeType.FacialHair,
                    FaceAttributeType.Glasses
                };
                var res = await detect.DetectWithStreamWithHttpMessagesAsync(picture,true,true,requiredFaceAttributes);
```